# How to split string by multiple delimiters in flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split, regexp-substr

This looks like a simple question, but I couldn't find any result after google.
I have string `tel：090-1234-9876 03-9876-4321　+81-90-1987-3254`, I want to split it to `tel：`, `090-1234-9876`, `03-9876-4321` and `+81-90-1987-3254`, what can I do?

Comment: use `[]` for regex as `or` and put any sign you want to split : `str.split(RegExp(r'[ 　：]'));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply you can use the `split()` method of the Dart as follows.

```
final str = "tel：090-1234-9876 03-9876-4321　+81-90-1987-3254";
print(str.split(" "));
```

If you want to use any other pattern, try splitting using regex.

```dart
final str = "tel: 090-1234-9876 03-9876-4321 +81-90-1987-3254";
print(str.split(RegExp(r'\s')));
// outputs: [tel:, 090-1234-9876, 03-9876-4321, +81-90-1987-3254]
```

Additionally, if you want to split by multiple delimiters e.g by +, -, and \s then

```dart
final str = "tel: 090-1234-9876 03-9876-4321 +81-90-1987-3254";
print(str.split(RegExp(r'[+-\s]')));
// outputs: [tel:, 090, 1234, 9876, 03, 9876, 4321, , 81, 90, 1987, 3254]
```

[Try Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dev/83f3fe5cc4e543edc6c18b43041a569c)

Answer (score 0):

Use dart's [`String.split(Pattern)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String/split.html) method!!

```dart
String telnums = 'tel：090-1234-9876 03-9876-4321　+81-90-1987-3254';

List<String> splitValues = telnums.split(" ");
```

In fact, you can use any regex ([`Regex`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)), [`String`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String-class.html) or pattern ([`Pattern`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Pattern-class.html))

Comment: what can I split `：`, ` ` and `　`? you only split one of them what I knew...

Comment: @mikezang, you could use regex to do that and could you please explain what do you mean by 'only split one of them'?

Comment: Your example didn't split on colon.  Colon is still part of the first element returned.